# How would I compare a date string like "Sun, Oct 3" to the current date?

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to remove a given element once the date passes the date in the string using append. Would I need to convert it first?

The date string above is listed in `h2` tags.

So far I've just done this to get access to the date:

```
var today = new Date();
let dates = document.getElementsByTagName("h2"); 

for(date of dates){ 
  console.log(date.innerHTML) 
}
```

Comment: How do you know if a date is the current, next or previous year?

Comment: Good question, the section is prefaced with "2021-22 Preseason Home Games" or "2021-22 Home Games"

Comment: That doesn't help. I don't know when the season starts or ends. Is Oct 3 2021 in the season 2021-22 or Oct 3 2022? Is Sep 1 in the past or future? Or Jul 1?

Comment: Season starts Oct 2021, ends around April 2022

Comment: I would use a date library (e.g. [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com), [Day.js](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs)) and parse the date for the years 2021 and 2022. Then I would read the weekday of that date and compare with the weekday of the string. Finally I would compare the actual date with the current date using the library.

Comment: There is nothing much in your current code.
You should at least get the current date, and try to parse your "human readable" date.

Comment: Instead of a library you could create an array of all months `['Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', ...]` and manually compare with the current date you get with [date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score -1):

You could try something along the lines of the following:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q, hC, aC, rC, tC; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id); mobile = /Mobi/i.test(nav.userAgent);
S = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
hC = (node, className)=>{
  return node.classList.contains(className);
}
aC = (node, ...classNames)=>{
  node.classList.add(...classNames);
  return aC;
}
rC = (node, ...classNames)=>{
  node.classList.remove(...classNames);
  return rC;
}
tC = (node, className)=>{
  node.classList.toggle(className);
  return tC;
}
// tiny library above for reuse on other loads - magic below can be put on another page except `}) // end load` line
let h2s = Q('h2'), dt = new Date, nd, yr;
dt.setHours(0); dt.setMinutes(0); dt.setSeconds(0); dt.setMilliseconds(0); 
yr = dt.getFullYear(); dt = dt.getTime();
for(let h2 of h2s){
  nd = new Date(h2.textContent.split(', ')[1]+', '+yr); nd.setHours(0);
  nd.setMinutes(0); nd.setSeconds(0); nd.setMilliseconds(0);
  if(nd.getTime() < dt)h2.remove();
}
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>&lt;h2&gt; Date Question</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <h2>Mon, Sep 27</h2>
  <h2>Tue, Sep 28</h2>
  <h2>Wed, Sep 29</h2>
  <h2>Thu, Sep 30</h2>
  <h2>Fri, Oct 1</h2>
  <h2>Sat, Oct 2</h2>
  <h2>Sun, Oct 3</h2>
</body>
</html>
```